# Write a c++ program that finds the number of vowels used in an string

Tags: c++

Write a c++ program that finds the number of vowels used in an string.

For the above problem I written a program as follows:

```
int main()
{   
    char x[10];
    int n,i,s=0;
    cout<<"Enter any string\n";
    cin>>x;
    n=strlen(x);
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        if(x[i]=='a'||x[i]=='e'||x[i]=='i'||x[i]=='o'||x[i]=='u')
        {
            s=s+1;
       }
    }
    cout<<s;
    return 0;
}
```

Output of the program is as:

> Enter any string 
>  elephant 
>  3

Here in 'elephant' at three places vowels are used but the total number of vowels used is 2(e and a) not 3

I am asking to improve the program so that it counts the total number of vowels and print the total number.(e.g. in case of elephant it must give 2)

Comment: The number of vowels used is `3`, the number of *different* vowels used is `2`. Which one do you want to calculate?

Comment: This smells like homework..

Comment: This definitely smells like homework

Comment: It's also significant that he's unable to clearly specify what he wants the program to do.  That's probably at the heart of the problem.

Comment: And with the exception of `cout` and `cin`, it's pure C.  Solving it in C++ would use completely different tools (like `std::string`, `std::find_if`, `std::sort` and `std::unique`, if you wanted to be fancy and show off a little).

Comment: i suggest u build up an array of all known words, and then connect the nb. of vowels to this string. 
e.g
StringList.push(elephant,2);
StringList.push(kidding, 1);

Comment: Why does it matter if it's actually homework or not?  He has stated the problem.  He has shown what he has done so far to solve the problem.  He has clearly stated the actual results and somewhat clearly stated the expected results.  The problem with the usual homework problem is that they're normally just a copy & paste of the assignment with no effort made, or there will be a ton of non-sense restrictions put on the student.

Comment: Please replace `char x[10];` by std::string - drop `n=strlen(x);`and replace `for(i=0;i<n;++i)` by for(i=0;i<x.size();++i)

Comment: This question, although quite basic, is better then plenty of non-homework questions I see posted.  I don't understand the downvotes or close votes.

Comment: @nhgrif: I would assume that the bad reception of the question in no little part comes from its tone. I often see questions with worse effort or quality being embraced happily because the asker asked in a nice fashion. In this case however, it sounds a lot like the OP was assigning us a job. "I am asking to improve the program" sounds a lot like "I am asking YOU to improve the program!" instead of the possibly intended "I am asking this question, so i can improve my program, please."

Comment: @nhgrif The problem (homework or no) is that his actual results are correct for the problem as he specified it.

Comment: @nhgrif: He hasn't done anything so far to attack this particular problem. He's presenting a solution to a different problem.

Comment: @DieterLücking Seems like a definition of "vowel" is also missing.  When I was learning English, I learned that a, e, i, o, u and sometimes y are vowels.  That "sometimes y" makes the problem distinctly non-trivial: "yet" has one vowel (the "e"), but "say" has two.

Answer (score 2):

Make another array(), with 5 index, like

```
 vowels[5] = array(0,0,0,0,0);
```

Then make if else if, with eache vowel, and add

```
 if(x[i] == 'a') vowels[0] =1;
 elseIf(x[i] == 'e') vowels[1] =1;
```

etc, and then check if vowels array is set to 1 or 0, and count only, these which are 5.

```
int count=0;
foreach vowels as item {
  if(item == 1) count++

}
return count;
```

Comment: +1 Simple pseudo code (no overkill) counting the amount of different vowels (just lacking case sensitivity, as the OP code does)

Comment: @DieterLücking But hardly a reasonable approach.  At least his initial code didn't need separate branches for each vowel.

Comment: @JamesKanze if, switch/case or a table of all chars - does it matter?

Comment: @DieterLücking And how.  Any solution which requires separate code for each different vowel is a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution would be to just insert each vowel you see
into an `std::set`, and use its `size` function when you're
done.

And for heaven's sake, use a table lookup to determine whether
something is a vowel (and put the logic in a separate function,
so you can correct it when you need to handle the "sometimes y"
part).

Alternatively, without using the standard algorithms:

```
int charCount[UCHAR_MAX + 1];

//  and for each character:

++ charCount[static_cast<unsigned char>( ch )];
```

(Of course, if you're using C++, you'll read the characters
into an `std::string`, and iterate over that, rather than having
an almost guaranteed buffer overflow.)

Then, just look at each of the vowels in the table, and count
those which have non-zero counts:

```
int results = 0;
std::string vowels( "aeiou" );  //  Handling the sometimes "y" is left as an exercise for the reader.
for ( auto current = vowels.begin(); current != vowels.end(); ++ current ) {
    if ( charCount[static_cast<unsigned char>( *current )] != 0 ) {
        ++ results;
    }
}
```

Of course, neither of these, implemented naïvely, will handle
upper and lower case correctly (where 'E' and 'e' are the same
vowel); using `tolower( static_cast<unsigned char>( ch ) )` will
solve that.

EDIT:

Since others are proposing solutions (which are only partially
correct):

```
bool
isVowel( unsigned char ch )
{
    static std::set<int> const vowels{ 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
    return vowels.find( tolower( ch ) ) != vowels.end();
}

int
main()
{
    std::string text;
    std::cout << "Enter any word:";
    std::cin >> text;
    std::set<unsigned char> vowelsPresent;
    for ( unsigned char ch: text ) {
        if ( isVowel( ch ) ) {
            vowelsPresent.insert( tolower( ch ) );
        }
    }
    std::cout << vowelsPresent.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Separating the definition of a vowel into a separate function is
practically essential in well written code, and at the very
least, you need to mask differences in case.  (This code also
punts on the question of "y", which would make `isVowel` several
orders of magnitude more difficult.  It also ignores characters
outside of the basic character set, so `"naïve"` will report two
different vowels.)

Comment: `std::count_if(begin(text), end(text), [](auto ch){ return isVowel(ch); }):`

Answer (score 1):

Sets already eliminate duplicates, so instead of counting vowels as you encounter them, add them into a set. Then, at the end, count the number of [non-duplicate] vowels by querying the set for its size.

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{   
    std::string x;
    int n = 0;
    std::set<char> vowels;

    std::cout << "Enter any string\n";
    std::cin >> x;
    n = x.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        if (x[i] == 'a' || x[i] == 'e' || x[i] == 'i' || x[i] == 'o' || x[i] == 'u')
           vowels.insert(x[i]);

    std::cout << vowels.size() <<'\n';
}
```

#### [Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d2b60ba92e00aa4)

> g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && echo "elephant" | ./a.out
>   Enter any string
>   2

Note that I also exchanged your use of fixed-sized arrays with an `std::string`, so that you're not at risk of dangerous circumstances when someone happens to input more than 9 characters.

Comment: And your code still has undefined behavior, at least if someone enters something like "confabulation".  Don't _ever_ suggest using `char[]` as a target of input, especially not to a beginner.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I wanted to minimise the number of semantic changes from his original code, but you're right — that's kind of irresponsible. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

I find a really easy way to solve this problem is by using `map <char, int>`.  This will allow you to make pairs, indexed by a `char`, ie. the vowels, and connect an integer counter to them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map <char, int> vowels;
    int n,i,s=0;
    string x;
    cout<<"Enter any string\n";
    cin>>x;
    for(i=0;i< x.length();++i)
    {
        if(x[i]=='a'||x[i]=='e'||x[i]=='i'||x[i]=='o'||x[i]=='u')
        {
            vowels[x[i]]++;
       }
    }

    for (map<char,int>::const_iterator print = vowels.begin(); print != vowels.end(); ++print){
        cout << print -> first << " " << print -> second << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For the string `elephant` we would get the following output:

```
a 1
e 2
```

By saying `vowels[x[i]]++;`  we are adding the found vowel into our map, if it already has not been added, and incrementing its paired `int` by one.  So when we find the first `e` it will add `e` to our map and increment its counter by one.  Then it will continue until it finds the next `e` and will see that it already has that indexed, so it will simply increment the counter to 2.  This way we will avoid the problem with duplicates.  Of course, if you wanted to get a single digit we could just print out the size of our map:

```
cout << vowels.size() << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay. My turn. To handle both upper and lower cases we convert to just lower:

```
std::string x("Elephant");
std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), x.begin(), std::function<int(char)>(std::tolower));
```

Now remove duplicates:

```
std::sort(x.begin(), x.end());
std::unique(x.begin(), x.end());
```

Now to count the vowels. I was hoping for something specific in locale but alas... Never mind we can create our own. Bit more complex, but not overly:

```
struct vowel : public std::ctype<char>
{
    static const mask* make_table()
    {
        static std::vector<mask> v(classic_table(), classic_table() + table_size);
        v['a'] |= upper;
        v['e'] |= upper;
        // etc.
        return &v[0];
    }
    vowel(std::size_t refs = 0) : ctype(make_table(), false, refs){}
};
```

While I am sure you can create your own but can't quite figure out how going by the documentation on cppreference so I say lower case vowels are uppercase. With the earlier call to std::tolower this should be safe.

With this we can use it easily like:

```
int i = std::count_if(x.begin(), x.end(), [](const char c)
{ 
    return std::isupper(c, std::locale(std::locale(""), new vowel)); 
});

std::cout << "Number of vowels:" << i << std::endl;
```

However I am not particularly happy with the two `std::locale` next each other.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution I can think of would be an array of bools representing each vowel and whether or not they've been counted.

```
bool vowelCounted[5] = { false };
```

Now, as you count the vowels:

```
if (x[i]=='a' && !vowelCounted[0]) {
    vowelCounted[0] = true;
    s += 1;
} else if (x[i]=='e' && !vowelCounted[1]) {
    vowelCounted[1] = true;
    s += 1;
}
```

And just repeat this structure for all 5 vowels.

The readability can be improved by using an `enum` rather than `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` for your indices... but you're using variables named `x[]` and `s`, so it's probably fine...

Answer (score 0):

If you use one of the standard containers (`vector`, `list`) add your vowels in there, do the same check as you're doing now, if it exists then remove it. When you're finished get the number of remaining elements, your answer will be the original count for the vowels minus the the remaining elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can create this:

```
std::vector< char> vowels;
```

And put into it all vowels that you meet while iterating through the string:

```
if(x[i]=='a'||x[i]=='e'||x[i]=='i'||x[i]=='o'||x[i]=='u')
                                               vowels.push_back( x[i]);
```

Then you can sort this and eliminate duplicates:

```
std::sort( vowels.begin(), vowels.end());
std::vector< char> vowels_unique( vowels.size());
std::vector< char>::iterator it;
it = std::unique_copy( vowels.begin(), vowels.end(), vowels_unique.begin());
vowels_unique.resize( std::distance( vowels_unique.begin(), it));
```

---

Even better, use a set property - it holds unique data, like this:

```
std::set< char> unique_vowels;
if(x[i]=='a'||x[i]=='e'||x[i]=='i'||x[i]=='o'||x[i]=='u')
                                               unique_vowels.insert( x[i]);
//...
int unique = unique_vowels.size();
```

Comment: That solution occurred to me too, but if you're using the standard library, what's wrong with inserting each vowel in an `std::set<char>`, and then using its `size` function at the end.

Comment: I agree, this would be better, I will add this to my answer

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for( string text; getline( cin, text ) && text != "q"; )
{
    set< char > vowels;
    copy_if( begin(text), end(text), inserter( vowels, begin(vowels) ), 
        []( char c ) { return std::char_traits< char >::find( "aeiou", 5, c ) != nullptr; } );
    cout << "the string [" << text << "] contains " << vowels.size() << " vowels" << endl;
}
```

You need the includes string, iostream, set, algorithm and iterator.
What do You want to do with the upper ones "AEIOU" ?

Answer (score 0):

### **C++ Code Snippet :**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    char s[100];
    int cnt;

    cnt=0;
    cin>>s;
    for(int i=0;s[i];i++)
    {
      char c =s[i];
      if(s[i]=='A' || s[i] =='E' || s[i]=='I' ||s[i]=='O'|| s[i]=='U')   cnt++;
      else if(s[i]=='a' || s[i] =='e' || s[i]=='i'||s[i]=='o' || s[i]=='u')  cnt++;
    }
    cout<<cnt<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Version utilizing `std::find()` and `std::transform()`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::getline;
using std::transform;

int main()
{
    cout << " Type sentence: ";
    string sentence;
    getline(cin, sentence);
    transform(sentence.begin(), sentence.end(), sentence.begin(), toupper);

    string vowels = "AEIOU";
    size_t vowCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vowels.length(); ++i)
    {
        if (sentence.find(vowels[i], 0) != string::npos)
        {
            ++vowCount;
        }
    }

    cout << "There is " << vowCount << " vowels in the sentence.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

**PROS**

- `std::find()` searches just for *first* occurrence of given vowel so there is no iteration over rest of the given string
- using optimized algorithms from `std`

**CONS**

- `std::transform()` transforms *each* lower-case letter regardless of its "vowelness"

Comment: The 4yo OP question sounds like homework. I guess he finished school already by now... Plus James Kanze already suggested this...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>   //std::cout
#include<string>     //std::string
#include<cctype>     //tolower()
#include<algorithm>  //std::for_each

using namespace std;

int main()

{

    string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    int count = 0;
    for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), [&count](char & c) //use of lambda func
    {
        c = tolower(c); //you can count upper and lower vowels
        switch (c)
        {
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
                count++;
                break;
        }
    });
    cout << count << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
char vowels[5] = {'a','e','i','o','u'};
char x[8] = {'e','l','e','p','h','a','n','t'};
int counts[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};
int i,j;

for(i=0;i<8;i=i+1)
{
    for(j=0;j<5;j=j+1)
    {
        if(x[i]==vowels[j])
        {
            counts[j] = counts[j] + 1;
        }
    }
}
for(i=0;i<5;i=i+1)
{
    cout<<counts[i]<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Since I was using the example of  'elephant' so I just initialized that.

If still any modification can be made then please edit it and make it more user friendly.